# Can scopes be chained conditionally in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Consider this code:

```
class Car
  scope :blue, -> { where(color: "blue") }
  scope :manual, -> { where(transmission: "manual") }
  scope :luxury, -> { where("price > ?", 80000) }
end

def get_cars(blue: false, manual: false, luxury: false)
  cars = Car.all
  cars = cars.blue if blue
  cars = cars.manual if manual
  cars = cars.luxury if luxury
end
```

Is there a way to chain these scopes like `Car.blue.manual.luxury` conditionally? I.e. only scope if the arg is true?

Comment: whats wrong with whatever you have done already? I think that should work

Comment: I want to do something like `Car.(blue if blue).(manual if manual).(luxury if luxury)` in a single line, building a single query, instead of calling each function and storing the partial result at each step

Comment: You're not storing a partial result, you're building a query step by step. The database won't be hit (i.e. no result partial or otherwise) until you try to do something with `cars` that requires the results.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord scopes can be applied conditionally, like this:

```
scope :blue, -> { where(color: 'blue') if condition }
```

Where `condition` is something you define that returns true or false. If the condition returns true, the scope is applied. If the condition is false, the scope is ignored.

You can also pass values into a scope:

```
scope :blue, ->(condition) { where(color: 'blue') if condition }
```

So, you could do something like this:

```
Task.blue(color == 'blue')
```

Which is similar to what the OP requested. But, why would you?

A better approach is something like this:

```
scope :color, ->(color) { where(color: color) if color.present? }
```

Which would be called like this:

```
Car.color('blue')  # returns blue cars
Car.color(nil)     # returns all cars

Car.color(params[:color])  # returns either all cars or only cars of a specific color, depending on value of param[:color]

Car.color(params[:color]).transmission(params[:transmission]).price(params[:price])
```

Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **yield_self**([read more here](https://bogdanvlviv.com/posts/ruby/new-method-kernel-yield_self-since-ruby-2_5_0.html)), new  functionality added in ruby 2.5 for it.

In your example:

```
class Car
  scope :blue, -> { where(color: "blue") }
  scope :manual, -> { where(transmission: "manual") }
  scope :luxury, -> { where("price > ?", 80000) }
end

def get_cars(blue: false, manual: false, luxury: false)
  cars = Car.all
            .yield_self { |cars| blue ? cars.blue : cars }
            .yield_self { |cars| manual ? cars.manual : cars }
            .yield_self { |cars| luxury ? cars.luxury : cars }
end
```